# ps1 script issue while executing in yaml ci pipeline

Tags: powershell, continuous-integration, devops

refs/heads/feature/nuget : The term 'refs/heads/feature/nuget' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,  script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is  correct and try again.

i have added a powershell script in ci yaml pipeline and i am taking input of source branch in ps1 script. but ps is saying command not found.

Comment: The powershell script or at least the line with the git command you are calling would help to answer your question without guessing.

Comment: the spellings are correct

Comment: What ist your command?

Comment: refs/heads/feature/nuget is the path of buildsourcebranch  im assigning it to a variable it is in $(build.sourceBranch) and assigning it to $string=$(build.sourceBranch)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you use the wrong variable syntax.

> refs/heads/feature/nuget is the path of buildsourcebranch im assigning it to a variable it is in $(build.sourceBranch) and assigning it to $string=$(build.sourceBranch)

If you use this variable directly inside the YAML (PowerShell inline) then $(Build.SourceBranch) would be correct **but if you want to use it insight a script (.ps1) then you have to call it with:**

```
  $sourceBranch = $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH
```

**Important: If you want to use the predefinied variables inside a script file its always a environment variable (env:) and you always have to replace the "." with "_"!**

```
YAML Inline: $(Build.SourceBranch) 
Script File: $env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH
```

Check out this sample in the docs:
[Pipeline: PowerShell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops#hello-world)